# What is the best way to design layout a screen on a tablet that's supposed to only show two button?

Tags: buttons, layout

I know that the simple answer will be just add two buttons on the screen and I'm good to go. But I just feel that it's awkward to just put two button on the center of a big screen, especially because the screens that follows the buttons cover the screen fully with controls and informations.

The two buttons are shown at first page after login. The buttons are for the user to select one of the two section to use, which each has a very distinct user interface and purpose, it feels like two apps in one. The second button is supposed to be used / tapped more frequently (daily) than the first one (can be monthly), but the first button opens a more important task than the second one.

This app on the tablet will be used by higher executive staffs, while the smartphone counterparts will be used by common staffs. Considering that this screen will be seen every time the user open the apps, do you have any suggestion on how to design this first screen so that it might deliver good first impression, but still does not distract the user? I know that I probably overthinking this, so any suggestion is appreciated. I never thought that design such very simple screen with very few controls can be very dilemmatic.

Comment: If one "mode" is used daily (multiple times per day?) and one only monthly (or so), then my first instinct would be to go straight to the "daily" mode and have a menu/icon/other-as-appropriate way of selecting the monthly/less-common option when it is needed (and possibly -- if it is known when this is needed -- to somehow indicate to the user that they should do the "monthly" task some time soon).

Comment: @TripeHound yeah, I was going to do with this by showing the first mode by default and add a button to the second mode, but ultimately I afraid it will put more emphasise to one mode and de-emphasise other. So I finally go with two large buttons. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would get straight to the point and just show the two options.

Since you have some space to spare, I would also add a quick description of each option. This helps new users find what they are looking for and returning users quickly recall the difference between the two options.

Quick mockup:

[image: 2 Option Screen]

Comment: After some thought and reading your answer, I finally use this solution with a little modification: I add a logo on top to reduce the space and to eat the excess white space away, and add the 2 (still) large buttons at the bottom, side by side. Thank you for elaborating with screenshot!